# How to get a response from Google's Dialogflow with Flask Socket-io chat app

Tags: python, api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

UPDATE 3:
From Miguel Grinberg: "Like most Google APIs, Dialogflow is incompatible with eventlet and gevent, and Google hasn't shown interest in adding support."

If anyone knows how I can get DialogFlow to work with flask-socketio, please let me know. Or more generally, what's a good way to build a python websocket chat app that also includes a bot.

UPDATE 2:

I found the culprit. At the top of my code, after import eventlet, I had this line:

```
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

This line blocks access to dialogFlow. When I comment it out, everything works fine. Unfortunately, I think this patch needs to be implemented for socketio to work.

More here:  https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/696

UPDATE 1:

I created another app following this tutorial: https://medium.com/zenofai/creating-chatbot-using-python-flask-d6947d8ef805

This app is much simpler, just focusing on dialogFlow. I used the same google project and dialogflow credentials as my original app. This new app works fine with dialogFlow. Why wouldn't dialogFlow work in my original app with same google project, credentials, and identical code blocks making the request to dialogFlow? Is there some kind of conflict with other parts of my flask socketio chat app?

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm trying to use Google's Dialogflow fulfillment in my flask socket-io chat app.

It hangs for a few minutes and then I get this error message:

```
Deadline of 220.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(<function _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable at 0x00000189C3C77C80>, session: "projects/webhook-agent-tmpe/agent/sessions/riverscuomo"
query_input {
  text {
    text: "howdy"
    language_code: "en"
  }
}
, metadata=[('x-goog-request-params', 'session=projects/webhook-agent-tmpe/agent/sessions/riverscuomo'), ('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.6.3 grpc/1.32.0 gax/1.21.0 gapic/1.1.0')]), last exception: 503 Deadline Exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Chatterbot instead: https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

It works with a Heroku-deployed flask-socketio chat app.